# AS3 Stop flickering of moving object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a ball moving around the screen, position updated on ENTER_FRAME. My problem is that there is a considerable amount of flicker going on. I have thought about using something like TweenLite to move the ball but as the position is being updated frame-to-frame I don't think that will work. I have increased the frame rate and reduced the speed the ball is travelling (and vice-versa) but that didn't help.

What can I do to reduce (preferably stop) the flickering?

[edit]
Here is the update function. Ball is a MovieClip.

```
public function update(e:Event):void {
    this.x += moveX;
    this.y += moveY;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and explain the flickering in more detail? Is the framerate stuttering or is it flashing on and off?

Comment: Sounds like a refresh problem due to low memory availability.

Comment: You don't happen to have 2 frames in your MC, 1 is the ball and the other is empty do you. I have done that before.

Comment: flash doesn't support vsync, and if your object is moving really fast, this could look like a flicker (vertical tearing of the page redraw)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'flickering' was being caused by my high frame-rate and moving the 'ball' several pixels at once. The result is that parts of the ball were being rendered in a different location to other parts of the ball per frame. To fix this I am now moving the ball only one pixel at a time and adjusting the frame-rate to control the speed of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

If you're code is something like this:

private function onEnterFrame(e:Event){
derp.x += 10;
}

there should be no flicker if derp is a movieclip. There might be fickering if you are using bitmapData on Bitmaps (depending on your logic)

but if you are using a movieclip like above, then no flicker should occur; it's probably your computer.

Upload you .swf so we can get a better picture of whats going on.